# Linq join two tables and count column

Tags: c#, sql, linq, list, c#-4.0

I have two tables.

**TableA**

```
TableAId value value2
 1        a     b
 2        aa    bb
```

**TableB**

```
TableBId TableAId  Status 
  1        1       success
  2        1       success
  3        2       failed
  4        2       failed
```

I am trying to create **list** like

```
   TableAId value value2 successCount errorCount
     1        a     b       2           0
     2        aa    bb      0           2
```

This is the query which I am trying to create but I am getting wrong results.

```
 var query = (from a in db.TableA.AsEnumerable()
                join b in db.TableB.AsEnumerable()
                on a.TableAId equals b.TableAId
                select
                new
                {
                    TableAId = a.TableAId,
                    value = a.value,
                    value2 = a.value2,
                    successCount = b.Status.Count(t => t.ToString() == "success"),
                    errorCount = b.Status.Count(t => t.ToString() == "failed")
                }).ToList();
```

Any help how I can correct the query would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what result you are getting after running this query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to group your rows by something first, otherwise the count doesn't make sense.

```
from a in db.TableA
join b in db.TableB on a.TableAId equals b.TableAId
group b by a into g
select new
{
    TableAId = g.Key.TableAId,
    value = g.Key.value,
    value2 = g.Key.value2,
    successCount = g.Count(t => t.Status == "success"),
    errorCount = g.Count(t => t.Status == "failed")
}
```

I also removed `AsEnumerable` calls to move the join, grouping and counting to the database - your query brings all the rows into application memory before performing the query using LINQ to Objects, which is in 99.9% of cases not what you want.